# ant and java 8 - "major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler"

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am trying to upgrade my ant project from java 7 to java 8.
(the project deployed in "Eclipse Kepler" with "Java™ 8 support to Eclipse Kepler SR2")

For that i downloaded ant 1.9.4 ( according this post http://wiki.eclipse.org/Ant/Java8) , and configure it's as my "ant home".

when i am trying to compile a got the following warning: 

 `"major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
 [javac]   It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded."`

But the compiler that defined for the workspace is 1.8. 
(In the ant configuration it's define the compiler to be the same compiler of the work space..)

Any idea whats happened?

Thanks a lot.

Eyal

Comment: What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please check that the tools.jar used by Ant is from JDK8 and not JDK7.

Window -> Preferences:

In the left pane, go to Ant -> Runtime. In the Classpath tab, check the Global Entries.

Answer (score 4):

This error usually comes when there is difference in the JDK version.Please check  classpath, java -version and JAVA_HOME set in the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add JAVA_HOME in the Classpath variables: Window->Java->Build Path->Classpath variables point to "path/to/jdk"

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, I simply fixed it by configure `javah` from jdk(either openjdk or oracle jdk works) 7 to 8:

```
$ javah -classpath . -d jni/ NativeSorting
./NativeSorting.class: major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
$ sudo update-alternatives --config javah
There are 4 choices for the alternative javah (providing /usr/bin/javah).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah   1081      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah   1081      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javah            1000      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javah           1000      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javah to provide /usr/bin/javah (javah) in manual mode
$ javah -classpath . -d jni/ NativeSorting
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all the other answers:
What solved this issue for me was deleting redundant/different java paths in the `PATH` environment variable.