# OpenJML "major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler”

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem that Eclipse comes with the error

```
"major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler"
```

When im trying to enable `OpenJML`

I have been reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106371/ant-and-java-8-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51-the-highest-major-version-s)

But it does not solve the problem.

When i run java -version the output is

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: You have compiled your code with JDK 8 and something is trying to use it with a JDK 7 compiler.

Comment: are you sure eclipse project is using jdk8?

Comment: If I go to preferences, "installed JREs" is Java SE 8(1.8.0_45) and the compiler is 1.8

Comment: I dont think OpenJML supports Java 8, and I think it needs the OpenJDK 7, I'm having the same issue I need a static verification tool for Java 8.