# Netbeans: JVM Creation fails after changing default JDK

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm, java-7, java-6

I have installed Netbeans 7.1 and its default JDK is version 1.6. Since I want to change it to version 1.7, I changed the following code in etc/netbeans.conf file

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_06"
```

to

```
netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0"
```

since JDK 1.7 file name is jdk1.7.0

After changing the file path when I reopen Netbeans, an error message will print as "JVM Creation failed". So I changed the file path back to the previous one and Netbeans started without giving an error message.
How can I change the default JDK version of Netbeans to 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, go to properties, go to libraries option, click on the manage platforms button, if you don't have Java 7 add it or else select the platform.

Comment: I did that. When the file is run an error message gets printed as `major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.`

Comment: Did you check this question and its answers [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106371/ant-and-java-8-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51-the-highest-major-version-s)